# vim cannot layout properly with eliminator

Tags: vim, terminator

I am using `terminator` as terminal emulator. Terminator allows to increase/decrease font size and also modifies the $COLUMNS and $LINES environment variables properly. `less` and `nano` seem to understand this change and display long files properly. But vi/vim does not seem to pick up this change and does not layout well (it does not display from the first line of the file).

[image]

At the time this occurs, the values of relevant environment variables are:

```
$  echo $LINES
47
$  echo $COLUMNS
198
```

installed software:

```
ii  vim                                                         2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1                       Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
ii  terminator                                                  0.96-0ubuntu1                              multiple GNOME terminals in one window
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stty columns <arg>` to change column width of window or `stty rows <arg>` to change the row height of the window.

For more info on stty refer this [page](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/stty.1.asp)

In vi/vim it uses the same settings as your terminal. In gvim or terminator to change the font size you can use `:set guifont=<value>` or you can set this value permanently in **.vimrc** file

Refer [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font) on how to change the font.

Hope this helps

Comment: my stty settings are the same as reported by eliminator. when eliminator says 88 * 50. this is the output of stty -a reports rows:50, columns:88. At this point, i still have the same issue of vi not displaying files from line one. Or may be I did not understand what you meant. Please explain. thanks.